# ¿Por qué no quiere dividir mi programa?

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
//Dada la matricula y 5 calificaciones de un alumno obtenidas a lo largo del
 //semestre, imprime la matricula del alumno y el promedio de sus calificaciones

using namespace std;

int main()

{ 
int MATRICULA = 12000;
int CAL1, CAL2, CAL3, CAL4, CAL5;
int PROMEDIO;

cout<< "NUMERO DE MATRICULA:";
cout<< MATRICULA<< endl;

cout<< "CAL1:";
cin>>CAL1;

cout<<"CAL2:";
cin>>CAL2;

cout<<"CAL3:";
cin>>CAL3;

cout<<"CAL4:";
cin>>CAL4;

cout<<"CAL5:";
cin>>CAL5;

PROMEDIO = CAL1 + CAL2 + CAL3 + CAL4 + CAL5 / 5;

cout<<"EL PROMEDIO TOTAL ES:"<< PROMEDIO << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme con este programa, al compilarlo da bien, pero al momento de darme un resultado no lo divide por el numero que le puse, aparece una respuesta que nada que ver, si alguien sabe como arreglar esto me ayudarian muchisimo, muchas gracias.

Comment: (CAL1 + CAL2 + CAL3 + CAL4 + CAL5) / 5;

Comment: precedencia de operadores `/` se evalúa antes que `+`

Comment: El promedio debe ser tipo `float`, a menos que solo quieras la parte entera y todo debe ir distribuido en paréntesis para determinar el orden aritmético `(A + B) / C`, no es lo mismo que `A + (B / C)` que en tu caso si suponemos que `B` es tu ultimo numero, `C` esta tomando el valor `B` como nominador.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu hacer esto `PROMEDIO = CAL1 + CAL2 + CAL3 + CAL4 + CAL5 / 5;` es equivalente a esto: `PROMEDIO = (CAL1 + CAL2 + CAL3 + CAL4) + (CAL5 / 5);` entonces para solucionar tu problema lo que tienes que hacer es poner paréntesis para que tengas una mayor precisión y lo pones asi:

`PROMEDIO = (CAL1 + CAL2 + CAL3 + CAL4 + CAL5) / 5;`

Answer (score 1):

Como menciona Alan,

El termino correcto es `(CAL1 + CAL2 + CAL3 + CAL4 + CAL5) / 5;`

El compilador sigue las reglas matemáticas, separación en términos

Es decir, primero se separan y resuelven los elementos que se encuentren entre paréntesis, luego los que están entre los signos de sumas y restas, para estos últimos podrías entenderlos mejor si pones un paréntesis.

```
A + B - C * B + D / C = A + B - (C * B) + (D / C)
```

Answer (score 1):

En efecto **(CAL1 + CAL2 + CAL3 + CAL4 + CAL5) / 5**, es lo correcto, te recomiendo que para empezar a programar este tipo de ejercicios visites:

[Operadores, Jerarquía de Operadores](https://abialeba.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/operadores-jerarquia-de-operadores-y-primeros-programas-en-c/) y [Operadores en C](http://lsi.vc.ehu.es/asignaturas/FdIc/labs/a1/htm/oper.html), o bien realices una búsqueda a cerca de estos temas, esto te ayudará bastante aunque para algunos parezca sencillo.